# Sticky Note (Post-it) - change size and keep in browser memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stickynote

I have two problems with sticky notes wrote in JS and jQuery.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/venntr/14fs0fef/15/)

1. I am using sticky note to write some data. But when I want change size, then only inside field is changing size? What am I doing wrong?
2. I try to keep note in browser memory when I unfortunately refresh page.

**Code**

```
var arr = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  function limitTextareaLine(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().split("\n").length >= $(this).attr('rows')) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  $(function() {
    $('textarea.limited').keydown(limitTextareaLine);
  });
  var x = "<div class='darkYellow'><span class='close ui-icon ui-icon-close' onclick='closeIt($(this));'>x</span>Note<div class='lightYellow'><textarea class='notatka' id='user' maxlength='250' rows='8' cols='25' class='limited'></textarea></div></div>";
  $('#click').click(function() {
    var count = $('.note').length + 1;
    $('.note').removeClass('active');
    $('#one').append('<div class="note ' + count + ' active">' + x + '</div>');
    arr.push(count);
    $(".darkYellow").draggable();
  });
  $('body').click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.parents('.note').length > 0) {
      $('.note').removeClass('active');
      target.parents('.note').addClass('active');
    }
    console.log(arr);
  });
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      if ($('.note').length > 0) {
        if ($('.note.active').length > 0) {
          var cls = parseInt($('.note.active').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
          var index = arr.indexOf(cls);
          console.log('.note.active.' + cls + ' ' + index);
          arr.splice(index, 1);
          $('.note.active').remove();
        } else {
          var cls = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
          var index = arr.indexOf(cls);
          arr.splice(index, 1);
          console.log('.note.' + cls + ' ' + index);
          $('.note.' + cls).remove();
        }
      }
      console.log(arr)
    }
  });
});

function closeIt(that) {
  var cls = parseInt(that.parent().parent().attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
  var index = arr.indexOf(cls);
  console.log('.note.' + cls + ' ' + index);
  arr.splice(index, 1);
  that.parent().parent().remove();
  localStorage.setItem('var', car);
}
```